# I can not upload a file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I cannot upload a file in codeigniter. Code I'm using:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->model('User_m');
    }
    public function form()
    {
        if($_POST){
            //print_r($_POST);exit;


                 if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
                 {
                   $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/";
                   $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                   $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                   //Load upload library and initialize configuration
                   //print_r($config);exit;
                   $this->load->library('upload',$config);
                   //$this->upload->initialize($config);

                   if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
                       $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                       $userfile = $uploadData['file_name'];
                       //echo $userfile;exit;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $userfile = '';
                   }
             }
             else
              {
                 $userfile = '';

              }
            $data['name']=$this->input->post('name');
            $data['email']=$this->input->post('email');
            $data['phone']=$this->input->post('phone');
            $data['userfile']=$userfile;
            $this->User_m->form_insert($data);
        }


        $this->load->view('form');
    }
}
```

This is my controller function code for processing multipart form data in codeigniter. But file is not uploading.

Comment: @SP can you show us your error ?

Comment: @M.Hemant There is no error.no file name is stored in userfile column in table.

Comment: Can you please add code of view file from where you are trying to upload file so that will be helpful in trying to fix the bug.

Comment: Use `$this->upload->display_errors()` in the ELSE part of this `if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))`

Comment: Yes,after add $this->upload->display_errors() it is showing error.That means if part not executing. @Danish Ali

Comment: <div id="container">
 <h1>Please Fill up the Registration Form.!</h1>

 <div id="body">
  <!--    <?php echo $error;?>  -->
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   Full name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   Email:<br>
   <input type="text" name="email"><br>
   Phone:<br>
   <input type="text" name="phone"><br><br>
   Image:<br>
   <input type="file" name="userfile" />

<br /><br />
   <input type="submit"><br>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>    This is my view File.

Comment: @SwetalinaRay what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

as you have given code i have modified code to trace it.Here below i have attached the view file as well as controller file :

1) Below is a view file code.In this i have submitted form by giving method name in action attribute.If you are submitting the form through ajax then you can pass the method name over there.

```
<div id="container">
<h1>Please Fill up the Registration Form.!</h1>
<div id="body">
  <!-- <?php echo $error;?> --> 
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url() . '/Main/form' ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data"> Full name:<br> <input type="text" name="name"><br> Email:<br> <input type="text" name="email"><br> Phone:<br> <input type="text" name="phone"><br><br> Image:<br> <input type="file" name="userfile" /> <br /><br /> <input type="submit"><br> </form>
</div>
</div>
```

2) Below is a controller code.

```
 <?php

 class Main extends CI_Controller {

 public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','html'));
    }

    public function index()
    {
           $this->load->view('form');
    }


    public function form()
{

    if($_POST){



             if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
             {
               $config['upload_path'] = "./uploads/";
               $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
               $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
               //Load upload library and initialize configuration
               //print_r($config);exit;
               $this->load->library('upload',$config);
               //$this->upload->initialize($config);

               if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
                   $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                   $userfile = $uploadData['file_name'];
                   //echo $userfile;exit;
               }
               else
               {
                   $userfile = '';
               }
         }
         else
          {
             $userfile = '';

          }
        $data['name']=$this->input->post('name');
        $data['email']=$this->input->post('email');
        $data['phone']=$this->input->post('phone');
        $data['userfile']=$userfile;

        // Below $data getting all the form data
        print_r($data);

    }


    $this->load->view('form');
}

}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: No,i am still facing the same problem.Can not upload file. @Sohil Chamadia

Comment: And even tell which file you are trying to upload I mean to say file extension is what? Because as per the above code only files can be uploaded whose extension is "jpg,jpeg,png and gif"

Comment: Array ( [name] => Swetalina [email] => swetalina22gmail.com [phone] => 9437444548 [userfile] => )     I have uploaded jpg file. @Sohil Chamadia

Comment: Write this code "$this->upload->display_errors()` in the ELSE part of this "if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))".and tell me any error occurred?

Comment: Yes,Got it.Now its working.Thank You. @Sohil Chamadia

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public function form()
    {
        if($_POST){    

                 if(!empty($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
                 {
                   $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                   $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                   $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                  $this->upload->initialize($config);
                   $this->load->library('upload',$config); 
                   if($this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){                      
                       $userfile = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

                   }
                   else
                   {
                       $userfile = '';
                   }
             }
             else
              {
                 $userfile = '';

              }
            $data['name']=$this->input->post('name');
            $data['email']=$this->input->post('email');
            $data['phone']=$this->input->post('phone');
            $data['userfile']=$userfile;
            $this->User_m->form_insert($data);
        }
```